# AVAssetResourceLoader does never send events for canceling AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest on a device

Tags: ios, objective-c

My application has the module of implementing AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate.

In case of running on Simulator, 
My module received events for canceling AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest from AVAssetResourceLoader.

```
- resourceLoader:didCancelLoadingRequest:
```

**But in case of running on Device**,
AVAssetResourceLoader does **never** send events for canceling AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest.

Why the simulator and the device operates differently?

Here are the sources that have the same problems.
https://github.com/Naituw/DemoAVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate

Thank you.

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you found some solution for this?